# Containing thrown exceptions in MDI child forms

Tags: .net, winforms, error-handling

I have a .NET MDI form based application.

I would like to contain errors thrown in a child form within that form so I can invalidate it without closing the entire application.

Is there a solution that does not involve catching all errors in Application.ThreadException?

Comment: Sounds like the structure of your program is too heavily tied to the user interface. What processing are you doing in the forms besides display that would crash the app? And... don't try to handle ALL exceptions. The rule of thumb with exception handling is handle only the exception you know you can handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot **capture all exceptions triggered from a particular windows form in one place**. The solution for your problem is detecting the **exact region** within the form that may potentially trigger an **invalidation exception** and invalidate the form on the catch.